# How to send hyperlink as response to dialogflow using python?

Tags: python, json, dialogflow-es

I have to send clickable hyperlink as response to dialogflow chatbot using python. I guess I need to convert hyperlink to JSON format in order to do that. But I am new to JSON and unable to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please add some example inputs you are working with in the question?

Comment: http://example.com suppose this is the link that i have to send to dialogflow as response via python.. In my code I am converting my text to JSON format and sending it as the response to dalogflow

Comment: which client are you using?